# get hour using createdAt and check if hour is equal hours.hour array if exists sum 1 to total else add hour and total object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have these documents, and i need to find the total by hours of the day,

but the values ​​are coming repeated, I needed to check before adding the hour to the hours array if there is already an object with that same hour, if there is, add 1 to the total, otherwise add the object with the respective hour and the total 1

https://mongoplayground.net/p/eB1Cy6W6sR8

```
[
  {"createdAt": {"$date": {"$numberLong": "1648205560872" }}},
  {"createdAt": {"$date": {"$numberLong": "1650541960872"}}},
  {"createdAt": {"$date": {"$numberLong": "1650531160872"}}},
  {"createdAt": {"$date": {"$numberLong": "1648205560714"}}},
  {"createdAt": {"$date": {"$numberLong": "1650541960872"}}},
  {"createdAt": {"$date": {"$numberLong": "1650538360872"}}}
]
```

i'm trying this way

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {}
},
{
  "$group": {
    _id: {
      $dateToString: {
        format: "%Y-%m-%d",
        date: "$createdAt"
      }
    },
    hours: {
      $push: {
        hour: {
          $hour: "$createdAt"
        },
        total: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

but the hours are returning again and again

```
[
  {
    "_id": "2022-03-25",
    "hours": [
      {"hour": 10,"total": 1},
      {"hour": 10,"total": 1}
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2022-04-21",
    "hours": [
      {"hour": 11,"total": 1},
      {"hour": 8,"total": 1},
      {"hour": 11,"total": 1},
      {"hour": 10,"total": 1}
    ]
  }
]
```

I wait for this return

```
[
  {
    "_id": "2022-03-25",
    "hours": [
      {"hour": 10,"total": 2},
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2022-04-21",
    "hours": [
      {"hour": 11,"total": 2},
      {"hour": 8,"total": 1},
      {"hour": 10,"total": 1}
    ]
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/eB1Cy6W6sR8

Answer (score 0):

To only have unique values, you need set

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {}
},
{
  "$group": {
    _id: {
      $dateToString: {
        format: "%Y-%m-%d",
        date: "$createdAt"
      }
    },
    hours: {
      $addToSet: {
        hour: {
          $hour: "$createdAt"
        },
        total: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Use `$addToSet` instead `$push`

Comment: but I need it to be incremented by 1 at this time if it already exists in the array

Comment: Totally different question?

Comment: if I use addToSet, all hours will come out with 1, what I want is to increment the hour if it has already been added to this array, if I contract to create the hour with the total 1